# Debian startup - start a daemon after postgresql

Tags: debian, postgresql, daemon, update

i'm configuring my debian server and i don't  manage to start a daemon correctly.

In order to start, my daemon has to find the Postgresql socket (located at /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432), but the daemon doesn't start.
I checked the logs, it's written:

> An error occured while loading the map layer: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections n Unix domain socket '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432' ?

At first, i used `update-rc.d mydaemon defaults`, and since the result was like that, i've tried `update-rc.d mydaemon start 30 2 3 4 5 . stop 30 0 1 6 .`, but the result is still the same.

I'm using Debian 6.0.6 (Squeeze), and postgre "rc.d start level" seems to be 23 since `ls /etc/rc3.d | grep postgre` returns `S23postgresql`.

rc.d script metainfo:

```
# Provides:          mydaemon                                                                                                                           
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs                                                                                                                        
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs                                                                                                                        
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5                                                                                                                           
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6                                                                                                                             
# Short-Description: mydaemon daemon                                                                                                           
# Description:       mydaemon daemon.
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

(and sorry for my english)

Comment: Please edit your question providing Debian version, and the current "rc.d start level" of postgresql (is it really 29?!?).

Comment: Edit done! Debian 6.0.6 Squeeze, postgre "rc.d start level" seems to be 23.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add metainfo in your rc-script like this (example from exim4 rc-script, your configuration will differ from this, check out the insserv documentation):

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          exim4
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $named $network $time
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $named $network
# Should-Start:      postgresql mysql clamav-daemon greylist spamassassin
# Should-Stop:       postgresql mysql clamav-daemon greylist spamassassin
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: exim Mail Transport Agent
# Description:       exim is a Mail Transport agent
### END INIT INFO
```

This metainfo is used by the insserv to setup your script in needed place of boot sequence.

Comment: I updated my post so you can see my metainfo, and i will try this when my server will be able to reboot.
The `should-start` should be the solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Lght, try to add 'postgresql' to 'Required-Start' field. Maybe this will help you. This field lets to know insserv to start postgresql before starting your rc-script.

Comment: I have to reconfigure another debian server, using a local computer, in order to solve this problem, so i'll will keep you abreast of this.